# I am getting error on using toHaveBeenCalled() in jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-testing-library

I am getting error on using toHaveBeenCalled, Please correct me where am going wrong

code:

jsx

```
 <item
  onClick={ load ? undefined : onClick}
>
```

test

```
test('render', () => {
const MockItems = jest.fn()
const prop = {
  onClick: MockItems,
}
const onclickProp=  output.find(item).props().onClick
onclickProp(undefined)

expect(props.onClick).toHaveBeenCalled()//error
```

}

error

```
 expect(props.onClick).toHaveBeenCalled()

 Warning: An update to null inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).

When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):

act(() => {
  /* fire events that update state */
});
/* assert on the output */
```

Comment: the reason you are getting the error is because you tried to change the state outside the react call stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the item is inside any other component as a child component you need to dive() on the wrapper component. Shallow rendering gives you access to only outer/parent component layout.

```js
describe('item parent Component', () => {
  let wrapper,instance
  
  beforeEach(() => {
    mockProps = {
      handleClick: jest.fn()
    }
    const component = (<parent {...mockProps} />)
    wrapper = shallow(component).dive()
  })
  
  it('item is clicked', () => {
    wrapper.find(item).simulate('click')
    expect(handleClick).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
)}
```

```html
<item onClick={ load ? undefined : onClick} >
```

Comment: handelCLick and mockProps are not available

Comment: you must have missed somthing. It is clearly in the same cope. Can you please attach full js and spec file?

Comment: you must have missed something. It is clearly in the same scope. Can you please attach full js and spec file?